# query met num_rows, bind_param and fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysqli

In this combination of num_rows, bind_param en fetch(_assoc).

I don't get any results in $salt = $saltuitkomst['salt'];

$user = 195

$rows is giving the number 1 as a result

No error messages

```
$saltqry = "SELECT
                    salt,
                    mw_gegevens_groep
            FROM 
                    mw_gegevens
            WHERE   
                    mw_gegevens_persnr = ?
            ";
            if(!$statement = $connection->prepare($saltqry))
            {
            echo "Query error:.". $connection->error();
            } else { 
                if(!$statement->bind_param('i', $user)){
                echo "bind param did not work";
                }else{
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->store_result();
                $rows = $statement->num_rows;   
                $saltuitkomst = $statement->fetch();
                }
            }
        if($rows == 0) {
                $salt='';
        } else {
                $salt = $saltuitkomst['salt'];
                echo '-'.$salt.'-';
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the `salt` is empty

Comment: No salt is somethnig like : /0Es0ETaUwL2PXnNND7Af

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$saltqry = "SELECT
                    salt,
                    mw_gegevens_groep
            FROM 
                    mw_gegevens
            WHERE   
                    mw_gegevens_persnr = ?
            ";
            if(!$statement = $connection->prepare($saltqry))
            {
            echo "Query error:.". $connection->error();
            } else { 
                if(!$statement->bind_param('i', $user)){
                echo "bind param did not work";
                }else{
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->store_result();
                $statement->bind_result($salt, $group); 
                $saltuitkomst = $statement->fetch();
                if($saltuitkomst) {
                   echo '-'.$salt.'-';
                } else {
                   $salt='';
                }
                $statement->close();
                }
        }
```

Comment: your welcome, is this the only solution? I have another qry, but it uses a * so bid_result will not work.

Comment: just add separated with commas all the fields of the table as parameters. Meaning if table has 3 fields id,name,email do a `bind_result($id,$name,$email);` in your query of course you will use `select id,name,email from table`